# Joomla 1.7 PHP Mail on localhost not working

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I'm new to joomla and i'm trying to send email using the standard contact form on J1.7. I set my mailer as default to PHP Mail and in from email field i put my gmail id. I'm running WAMP 2.0 and on my local host Windows 7 .
I couldn't get to configure the email on the localhost using PHP Mail.

Thanks

Comment: If you are new to Joomla, why are you using Joomla 1.7? Joomla 2.5 is the recommended current long term release.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use PHP mail you should check the settings on the php.ini . Just look for [mail function] section. However, if you didn't have a smtp server on your local machine you'll end setting up a external smtp server to execute the PHP mail function.

At this point, I think it's more easy to configure Joomla! email to an external smtp. Here you have a link to joomla doc which show how to send emails using Gmail : [docs.joomla.org/How_do_I_use_Gmail_as_my_mail_server](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_I_use_Gmail_as_my_mail_server%3F)

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set up [a gmail account for SMTP](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_I_use_Gmail_as_my_mail_server?).

Answer (score 0):

Actually You can not test mails on a localhost server. You will have to upload it to a server. But there is a way to do it. [Read this](http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/). [This too](http://www.conticreative.com/The-Conticreative-Joomla-Blog/joomla-email-localhost.html).